# Is $\frac{f'}{f}$ bounded for $f$ convex, $f>c$?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, convex-analysis

Let $c>0$, $f\colon \mathbb{R} \to [c,\infty)$ be differentiable and convex.

Do we have

$$ \left\|\frac{f'}{f}\right\|_{\infty} < \infty ?$$

This seems to be true in simple examples, but I am not sure whether this is true in general, so I would appreciate some hint or a counterexample.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is false : take $f : x \mapsto e^{x^2}$. This is convex, but $f'(x) \gg f(x)$ as $x$ tends to infinity.